# Maximum value of $(x_{1}.x_{3}.x_{5})$

Tags: inequality

If $(x-x_{1}).(x-x_{2})+(x-x_{2}).(x-x_{3})+(x-x_{3}).(x-x_{4})+(x-x_{4}).(x-x_{5}) = 0$ have equal

roots with $x_{2}=x_{4}=k$ and $(x_{1}\;,x_{3}\;,x_{5}>0)\;,$ Then Max. value of $x_{1}.x_{3}.x_{5}$ in terms of $k$

My Try:: after multipliying we get $4x^2-2x.\left(x_{1}+2k+2x_{3}+x_{5}\right)+k.\left(x_{1}+2x_{3}+x_{5}\right)=0$

Now for equal  roots, Discriminant $ = 0$

$\left(x_{1}+2k+2x_{3}+x_{5}\right)^2=4k.\left(x_{1}+2x_{3}+x_{5}\right)$

Now How can I solve after that Help required, Thanks

Comment: For a multiply dot, you can use \cdot to get $1 \cdot 2$ instead of a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Now you could notice the match of $x_1+2x_3+x_5$ on both sides.  Let $y=x_1+2x_3+x_5$ and we have $(y+2k)^2=y+4ky+4k^2=4ky$, so $y+4k^2=0$.  OOPS-we have $y \le 0$ but you told us that $(x_{1}\;,x_{3}\;,x_{5}>0)$